# pyspark in local mode memory keeps adding up

Tags: pyspark, out-of-memory, local

I only process two rows of records, and it consumes a lot of memory.
I use Mac which has 6 scores and 16 GB

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("loc")
    .master("local[2]")
    .config("spark.driver.bindAddress","localhost")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "12g")
    .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "1500")
    .config("spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity", "20000")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
    .getOrCreate()
)
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

class CDATransformation:
    def __init__(
        self
    ):
        pass

    def preprocess_cda(self, cda_subset):
        print("***CDA PREPROCSSING***")
        return self._preprocess_cda(cda_subset)

    def _preprocess_cda(self, cda_subset):  # pragma: no cover
        df = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "EffectiveTime",
            F.when(
                cda_subset["EffectiveTime"].endswith("Z"), cda_subset["EffectiveTime"]
            ).otherwise(F.concat(cda_subset["EffectiveTime"], F.lit("Z"))),
        )
  
       def process_orderh_step_1(self, cda_subset):
        schema = ArrayType(
            StructType(
                [
                    StructField(
                        "Codes", ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
                    ),
                    StructField(
                        "ComponentResults",
                        ArrayType(
                            StructType(
                                [
                                    StructField(
                                        "Codes",
                                        ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType())),
                                    ),
                                    StructField("ComponentName", StringType()),
                                    StructField("EffectiveDateTime", StringType()),
                                    StructField("ResultValue", StringType()),
                                    StructField("ResultUnit", StringType()),
                                    StructField("ReferenceRange", StringType()),
                                    StructField("Status", StringType()),
                                ]
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    StructField("EffectiveDateTime", StringType()),
                    StructField("ReferenceId", StringType()),
                    StructField("Narrative", StringType()),
                    StructField("Impression", StringType()),
                ]
            )
        )

        df1 = (
            cda_subset.withColumn(
            "first_array",
            F.from_json(
                F.col("OrderHistory"), schema=schema),
            ).drop("OrderHistory")
             .withColumn(
            "lab_array", F.explode_outer(F.col("first_array"))
            ).drop("first_array")
             .withColumn(
            "main_id", F.concat_ws("#", F.col("EID"), F.col("EffectiveTime"))
            ).drop("EID", "EffectiveTime")
        )

        return df1

    def process_orderh_step_2(self, cda_subset):
        df1 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "lab_array", F.explode_outer(F.col("first_array"))
        ).drop("first_array")
        df2 = df1.withColumn(
            "main_id", F.concat_ws("#", F.col("EID"), F.col("EffectiveTime"))
        ).drop("EID", "EffectiveTime")
        return df2

    def process_orderh_step_3(self, cda_subset):
        df1 = (
                  cda_subset.withColumn(
                "comp_results_item", F.explode_outer(F.col("lab_array.ComponentResults"))
            ).drop("lab_array")
             .select(
            "*",
            F.col("comp_results_item.ComponentName"),
            F.col("comp_results_item.EffectiveDateTime"),
            F.col("comp_results_item.ResultValue"),
            F.col("comp_results_item.ReferenceRange"),
            ).drop("comp_results_item")
             .withColumn(
            "EffectiveDateTime",
            F.when(
                F.col("EffectiveDateTime").endswith("Z"), F.col("EffectiveDateTime")
            ).otherwise(F.concat(F.col("EffectiveDateTime"), F.lit("Z"))),
        )
        )
     

        df5 = df1.withColumn(
            "EffectiveDateTime",
            F.to_timestamp("EffectiveDateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),
        ).withColumn(
            "Period_Start_Date", F.split(F.col("Period_Start_Date"), r"\+")[0]
        )

        df6 = df5.withColumn(
            "Start_Date", F.to_date("Period_Start_Date")
        ).withColumn(
            "later",
            F.when(F.col("EffectiveDateTime") > F.col("Start_Date"), 1).otherwise(0),
        )

        # df7 = df6.withColumn(
        #     "later",
        #     F.when(
        #         F.col("EffectiveDateTime") > F.col("Period_Start_Date"), 1
        #     ).otherwise(0),
        # )
        # log.info("step 3 df7")
        # df7.printSchema()
        # df7.show(truncate=False)
        return df6

    def process_orderh_step_4(self, cda_subset):
        df1 = cda_subset.filter(cda_subset["later"] == 1)
        # log.info("step 4 df1")
        # df1.printSchema()
        # df1.show(truncate=False)
        pattern_number_dot = r"([0-9.]+)"

        df2 = df1.withColumn(
            "lower_bound", F.split(F.col("ReferenceRange"), "-").getItem(0)
        ).withColumn(
            "upper_bound_1", F.split(F.col("ReferenceRange"), "-").getItem(1)
        ).withColumn(
            "upper_bound",
            F.regexp_extract(F.col("upper_bound_1"), pattern_number_dot, 1),
        ).drop("upper_bound_1").withColumn(
            "lower_bound", F.col("lower_bound").cast("float")
        ).withColumn("upper_bound", F.col("upper_bound").cast("float"))
        # log.info("step 4 df2")
        # df2.printSchema()
        # df2.show(truncate=False)

        return df2

    def process_orderh_step_5(self, cda_subset):
        pattern_number_dot = r"([0-9.]+)"
        df1 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "smaller",
            F.when(
                F.col("ResultValue").startswith("<"),
                F.regexp_extract(F.col("ResultValue"), pattern_number_dot, 1),
            ).otherwise(None),
        ).withColumn(
            "smaller", F.col("smaller").cast("float")
        ).withColumn(
            "hyphen_smaller",
            F.when(F.col("smaller") < F.col("lower_bound"), 1).otherwise(0),
        ).drop("smaller")

        return df1

    def process_orderh_step_6(self, cda_subset):
        pattern_number_dot = r"([0-9.]+)"
        df1 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "larger",
            F.when(
                F.col("ResultValue").startswith(">"),
                F.regexp_extract(F.col("ResultValue"), pattern_number_dot, 1),
            ).otherwise(None),
        ).withColumn(
            "larger", F.col("larger").cast("float")
        ).withColumn(
            "hyphen_larger",
            F.when(F.col("larger") > F.col("upper_bound"), 1).otherwise(0),
        ).drop("larger")

        return df1

    def process_orderh_step_7(self, cda_subset):
        df1 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "result_value_num", F.col("ResultValue").cast("float")
        )
        # log.info("step 7 df1")
        # df1.printSchema()
        # df1.show(truncate=False)

        df2 = df1.withColumn(
            "hyphen_abnormal",
            F.when(
                (F.col("result_value_num") < F.col("lower_bound"))
                | (F.col("result_value_num") > F.col("upper_bound")),
                1,
            ).otherwise(0),
        )
        # log.info("step 7 df2")
        # df2.printSchema()
        # df2.show(truncate=False)
        return df2

    def process_orderh_step_8(self, cda_subset):
        pattern_number_dot = r"([0-9.]+)"
        df1 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "smaller_than_ref",
            F.when(
                F.col("ReferenceRange").startswith("<"),
                F.regexp_extract(F.col("ReferenceRange"), pattern_number_dot, 1),
            ),
        ).withColumn(
            "smaller_than_ref", F.col("smaller_than_ref").cast("float")
        ).withColumn(
            "smaller_abnormal",
            F.when(F.col("result_value_num") > F.col("smaller_than_ref"), 1).otherwise(
                0
            ),
        )

        return df1

    def process_orderh_step_9(self, cda_subset):
        pattern_number_dot = r"([0-9.]+)"
        df1 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "larger_than_ref",
            F.when(
                F.col("ReferenceRange").startswith(">"),
                F.regexp_extract(F.col("ReferenceRange"), pattern_number_dot, 1),
            ),
        ).withColumn(
            "larger_than_ref", F.col("larger_than_ref").cast("float")
        ).withColumn(
            "larger_abnormal",
            F.when(F.col("result_value_num") < F.col("larger_than_ref"), 1).otherwise(
                0
            ),
        )

        return df1

    def process_orderh_step_10(self, cda_subset):
        drop_col = [
            "lower_bound",
            "upper_bound",
            "hyphen_smaller",
            "hyphen_larger",
            "result_value_num",
            "hyphen_abnormal",
            "smaller_than_ref",
            "smaller_abnormal",
            "larger_than_ref",
            "larger_abnormal",
        ]
        df1 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "abnormal_cur",
            (
                F.col("hyphen_smaller")
                + F.col("hyphen_larger")
                + F.col("hyphen_abnormal")
                + F.col("smaller_abnormal")
                + F.col("larger_abnormal")
            ),
        ).drop(*drop_col)
        # log.info("step 10 df1")
        # df1.printSchema()
        # df1.show(truncate=False)

        windowSpecAgg = (
            Window.partitionBy(["main_id", "ComponentName"])
            .orderBy("EffectiveDateTime")
            .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
        )
        df2 = df1.select(
            "*",
            F.last("abnormal_cur").over(windowSpecAgg).alias("latest_value"),
            F.last("ResultValue").over(windowSpecAgg).alias("latest_result"),
        ).dropna(subset=["ComponentName"])
        # log.info("step 10 df2")
        # df2.printSchema()
        # df2.show(truncate=False)

        df3 = df2.dropDuplicates(subset=["main_id", "ComponentName"]).drop(
            "ReferenceRange", "later", "abnormal_value"
        )
        # log.info("step 10 df3")
        # df3.printSchema()
        # df3.show(truncate=False)

        return df3

    def process_orderh_step_11(self, cda_subset):
        df1 = cda_subset.groupby("main_id").agg(
            F.sum("latest_value").alias("sum_all_severity_codes_current")
        )
        # log.info("step 11 df1")
        # df1.printSchema()
        # df1.show(truncate=False)
        # rename column
        prefix_name = "orderH_"
        df2 = cda_subset.withColumn(
            "ComponentName", F.concat(F.lit(prefix_name), F.col("ComponentName"))
        )
        # log.info("step 11 df2")
        # df2.printSchema()
        # df2.show(truncate=False)

        df3 = (
            df2.groupby("main_id")
            .pivot("ComponentName")
            .agg(F.first(F.col("latest_result")))
        )
        # log.info("step 11 df3")
        # df3.printSchema()
        # df3.show(truncate=False)

        df4 = df1.join(df3, on="main_id")
        # log.info("step 11 df4")
        # df4.printSchema()
        # df4.show(truncate=False)

        df5 = (
            df4.withColumn("EID", F.split(F.col("main_id"), "#").getItem(0)).withColumn(
                "EffectiveTime", F.split(F.col("main_id"), "#").getItem(1)
            )
        ).drop("main_id")
        # log.info("step 11 df5")
        # df5.printSchema()
        # df5.show(truncate=False)
        return df5

    def process_orderh_step_12(self, cda_subset):
        df1 = cda_subset.select(
            "main_id", F.col("lab_array.Narrative").alias("narrative")
        )
        # log.info("step 12 df1")
        # df1.printSchema()
        # df1.show(truncate=False)

        df2 = df1.withColumn(
            "narrative",
            F.when(F.col("narrative") == "", None).otherwise(F.col("narrative")),
        )
        # log.info("step 12 df2")
        # df2.printSchema()
        # df2.show(truncate=False)

        df3 = df2.groupby("main_id").agg(
            F.collect_list("narrative").alias("orderH_narrative")
        )
        # log.info("step 12 df3")
        # df3.printSchema()
        # df3.show(truncate=False)

        df4 = (
            df3.withColumn("EID", F.split(F.col("main_id"), "#").getItem(0)).withColumn(
                "EffectiveTime", F.split(F.col("main_id"), "#").getItem(1)
            )
        ).drop("main_id")
        return df4

    def process_orderh(self, cda_subset):
        df7_0 = cda_subset.drop("OrderHistory")
        df7_1 = self.process_orderh_step_1(cda_subset)
        # df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_2(df7_1)
        # step3 has later to know if it is before or after Period_Start_Date
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_3(df7_1)
        # filter later == 1, keep the current results
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_4(df7_2)
        # step 5 hyphen smaller than lower bound ResultVale has <
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_5(df7_2)
        # step 6 hyphen larger than upper_bound ResultVale has >
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_6(df7_2)
        # step 7 out of reference range
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_7(df7_2)
        # step 8 ReferenceRange begins with <
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_8(df7_2)
        # step 9 ReferenceRange begins with >
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_9(df7_2)
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_10(df7_2)
        df7_2 = self.process_orderh_step_11(df7_2)
        # log.info("inside orderhistory")
        # log.info("df7_2")
        # df7_2.show()
        # extract narrative
        df7_12 = self.process_orderh_step_12(df7_1)
        # log.info("inside orderhistory")
        # log.info("df7_12")
        # df7_12.show()
        df7_2 = df7_0.join(df7_2, on=["EID", "EffectiveTime"], how="left")
        # log.info("inside orderhistory")
        # log.info("df7_2")
        # df7_2.show()
        df7_2 = df7_2.join(df7_12, on=["EID", "EffectiveTime"], how="left")
        log.info("step orderhistory 7_2")
        df7_2.printSchema()
        df7_2.show(truncate=False)
        return df7_2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cda_transform = CDATransformation(
        params["cda"]["client"],
        params["cda"]["cda_features"],
        params["cda"]["icd10_to_hcc_dict"],
        params["cda"]["hcc_to_score_dict"],
    )
    df1 = cda_transform.preprocess_cda(df)
```

Most memory consumed function is process_orderh, and I want to see how much memory it consumes,  I call an action: df7_2.show(truncate=False), and it consumes more than 1 GB for processing only two rows of record.

I check the memory increase process, in function process_orderh, it calls 12 functions, after each function call, the memory continues increasing. I continue to assign function output to the same variable df7_2, (dataframe created in these 12 functions (function name begins with process_orderh_step) should be garbage collected and release the momory), and the biggest dataframe has at most 20 rows and 30 columns, how can it consume so much memory?

Thanks

Comment: would you mind sharing those 2 rows input data?

Comment: try to remove this line `.config("spark.driver.memory", "12g")`, your spark application would not consume as much memory as it is now

Comment: I tried remove this line .config("spark.driver.memory", "12g"), it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data, csv format

```
EID,EffectiveTime,OrderHistory,dummy_col,Period_Start_Date
11,2019-04-19T02:50:42.6918667Z,"[{'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-2'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T23:48:00Z', 'ComponentResults': [{'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-1'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_1', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T00:35:41Z', 'ResultValue': '500', 'ResultUnit': 'mg/dL', 'ReferenceRange': '<10 mg/dL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-2'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_2', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T00:35:41Z', 'ResultValue': '2.2', 'ResultUnit': 'K/uL', 'ReferenceRange': '2.0 - 8.0 K/uL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '11-2'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T23:48:00Z', 'Status': 'completed'}], 'ReferenceId': 'Result1038007636', 'Narrative': '', 'Impression': ''}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-8'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T23:48:00Z', 'ComponentResults': [{'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-3'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_3', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T00:15:46Z', 'ResultValue': '2.9', 'ResultUnit': 'K/uL', 'ReferenceRange': '4.0 - 11.0 K/uL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-1'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_1', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T00:15:46Z', 'ResultValue': '30', 'ResultUnit': 'mg/dL', 'ReferenceRange': '<10 mg/dL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-4'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_4', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T00:15:46Z', 'ResultValue': '11.7', 'ResultUnit': '%', 'ReferenceRange': '<16.8 %', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-5'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_5', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T00:15:46Z', 'ResultValue': '1.2', 'ResultUnit': 'K/uL', 'ReferenceRange': '2.0 - 8.0 K/uL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '11-8'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T23:48:00Z', 'Status': 'completed'}], 'ReferenceId': 'Result1038007637', 'Narrative': 'narrative_1', 'Impression': ''}]",dummy_value_1,2019-04-18T23:29:27+00:00
12,2019-04-19T02:50:42.5618605Z,"[{'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '2-7'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T03:06:00Z', 'ComponentResults': [{'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-6'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_6', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T04:01:57Z', 'ResultValue': '<1.4', 'ReferenceRange': '10.0 - 30.0 ug/mL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '298-7'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T03:06:00Z', 'Status': 'completed'}], 'ReferenceId': 'Result1037565237', 'Narrative': 'narrative_21', 'Impression': ''}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '2-8'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T03:06:00Z', 'ComponentResults': [{'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-6'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_6', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T03:01:57Z', 'ResultValue': '<0.5', 'ReferenceRange': '10.0 - 30.0 ug/mL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-1'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_1', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T06:05:40Z', 'ResultValue': '20', 'ResultUnit': 'mg/dL', 'ReferenceRange': '<10 mg/dL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '5643'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T03:06:00Z', 'Status': 'completed'}], 'ReferenceId': 'Result1037565232', 'Narrative': '', 'Impression': ''}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '2-9'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T03:06:00Z', 'ComponentResults': [{'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-1'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_1', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T04:05:40Z', 'ResultValue': '5', 'ResultUnit': 'mg/dL', 'ReferenceRange': '<10 mg/dL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-4'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_4', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T04:05:40Z', 'ResultValue': '18', 'ResultUnit': '%', 'ReferenceRange': '<16.8 %', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '1-5'}], 'ComponentName': 'component_5', 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-19T04:05:40Z', 'ResultValue': '100', 'ResultUnit': 'K/uL', 'ReferenceRange': '2.0 - 8.0 K/uL', 'Status': 'completed'}, {'Codes': [{'CodeSystem': 'sys_1', 'Code': '2-4'}], 'EffectiveDateTime': '2019-04-18T03:06:00Z', 'Status': 'completed'}], 'ReferenceId': 'Result1037565229', 'Narrative': 'narrative_22', 'Impression': ''}]",dummy_value_2,2019-04-19T13:29:27+00:00
```